# Any way to impove code with several if nested?

Tags: python

I wrote this code with nested `if else` cases, but I feel it's so ugly and wonder if there's any way to improve it (or any better way to accomplish this).

```
def do_something(self, response):
    a_url = response.css('a.classA::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if a_url:
        a_url = a_url.split('&')[0]
    else:
        a_url = response.css('a.classB::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if a_url:
            a_url = a_url.split('&')[0]
        else:
            logger.error('get no url')
    if a_url:
        yield Request(
            url=a_url,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.do_next_thing
        )
```

The main concern is that I wanna extract a url/link from a response, and then **split** it and get the first element. But **a_url** only exists in one of two(or may be more) elements. I can't do the **split** directly because **a_url** may be `NoneType`. I wanna try with `try except else` but that seems getting even more complicated.

Any better solutions?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do it like this:

```
def do_something(self, response):
    a_url = (
        response.css('a.classA::attr(href)').extract_first()
        or
        response.css('a.classB::attr(href)').extract_first()
    )

    if not a_url:
        logger.error('get no url')
        return # or raise an exception and let the caller do the logging

    yield Request(
        url=a_url.split('&')[0],
        dont_filter=True,
        callback=self.do_next_thing
    )
```

This uses the short-circuit behaviour of the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or):

> The expression `x` or `y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its
>   value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value
>   is returned.

It also uses the "early return" technique, i.e. the failure case is handled first, and then the "normal" case can be done outside of any `if` or `else`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to simplify this code is to select both classes in scrappy in the first place:

```
def do_something(self, response):  
    a_url = response.css("a.classA::attr(href), a.classB::attr(href)")
    if a_url:   
        yield Request(
            url=a_url.split('&')[0],
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.do_next_thing
        )
    else:
        logger.error('get no url')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider splitting the method into two (later on even three) ones. Because as I see it, the first lines are more of a preparation than of actual logic. Something like this:

```
def prepare_something(self, response):
  a_url = response.css('a.classA::attr(href)').extract_first()
  if a_url:
    return a_url.split('&')[0]
  else:
    a_url = response.css('a.classB::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if a_url:
      return a_url.split('&')[0]
    else:
      logger.error('get no url')
      return None


def do_something(self, response):
  a_url = self.prepare_something(response)
  if a_url:
    yield Request(
      url=a_url,
      dont_filter=True,
      callback=self.do_next_thing
    )
```

This way, imho, the code is a little bit cleaner, and you are able to see that you might want to refactor the `prepare_something` method, like the following:

```
def get_a_url_part(self, response, path):
  a_url = response.css(path).extract_first()
  return a_url.split('&')[0] if a_url else None

def prepare_something(self, response):
  a_url = self.get_a_url_part(response, 'a.classA::attr(href)')
  b_url = self.get_a_url_part(response, 'a.classB::attr(href)')
  return a_url if a_url else b_url

def do_something(self, response):
  a_url = self.prepare_something(response)
  if a_url:
    yield Request(
      url=a_url,
      dont_filter=True,
      callback=self.do_next_thing
   )
```

From my point of view this could be considered an improvement.

Regards :)